# How to insert counts of rows by joining 3 tables on sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to join 3 tables and get counts of each contact's cases. So far I have this query written, but the result shows me contacts who has cases. I'd like to have a new column where it would show me "No of cases" for each contact, so the result should be 3 rows, 3 columns (last column is counts of cases)

Table A (Contacts)

```
+-----------------------+----+---------------------------------+
| Name                  | id | Organization                    |
+-----------------------+----+---------------------------------+
| Heidi Wilson-Reynolds | 2  | Alabama Arts Services           |
+-----------------------+----+---------------------------------+
| Dr. Andrew Zope       | 3  | Connecticut Empowerment Academy |
+-----------------------+----+---------------------------------+
| Rolando Cooper Sr.    | 8  | Dutton Advocacy Trust           |
+-----------------------+----+---------------------------------+
```

Table B (Case Contacts)

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | case_id | contact_id |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | 2          |
+----+---------+------------+
| 2  | 2       | 3          |
+----+---------+------------+
| 3  | 3       | 8          |
+----+---------+------------+
| 4  | 4       | 2          |
+----+---------+------------+
| 5  | 5       | 3          |
+----+---------+------------+
| 6  | 6       | 8          |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Table C (Cases)

```
+----+-----------+
| id | status_id |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 4  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 5  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 6  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    A.display_name AS 'Name',
    A.organization_name AS 'Organization'
FROM
    A
        INNER JOIN
    B ON A.id = B.contact_id
        INNER JOIN
    C ON B.case_id = C.id
WHERE
    A.contact_type = 'Individual' and C.status_id = 1; # Case status 1 is "Ongoing"
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Name                  | Organization                    |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Heidi Wilson-Reynolds | Alabama Arts Services           |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Dr. Andrew Zope       | Connecticut Empowerment Academy |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Rolando Cooper Sr.    | Dutton Advocacy Trust           |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Heidi Wilson-Reynolds | Alabama Arts Services           |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Dr. Andrew Zope       | Connecticut Empowerment Academy |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Rolando Cooper Sr.    | Dutton Advocacy Trust           |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
```

This is the result I would like it to show, I think I need to use COUNT() function:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| Name                  | Organization                    | number_of_cases |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| Heidi Wilson-Reynolds | Alabama Arts Services           | 2               |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| Dr. Andrew Zope       | Connecticut Empowerment Academy | 2               |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| Rolando Cooper Sr.    | Dutton Advocacy Trust           | 2               |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag based on the MySQL Workbench tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by

```
  SELECT 
      A.display_name AS 'Name',
      A.organization_name AS 'Organization',
      count(*) AS 'number_of_cases'

  FROM
      A
          INNER JOIN
      B ON A.id = B.contact_id
          INNER JOIN
      C ON B.case_id = C.id
  WHERE
      A.contact_type = 'Individual' and C.status_id = 1; # Case status 1 is "Ongoing"
  GROUP BY  A.display_name,  A.organization_name
```

The count(*) count the number of row that match the same value for the grouped by column .. in your case you have three distinct value for (name, Organization)

the the group by clause return this  three different rows .. ad for each of this row count the number of rows that have the same value for name and Organization.

In you sample all the three value for (name, Organization) have 2 rows each ..

see this for brief tutorial for aggregation function

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-aggregate-functions-sql-tutorial/

Comment: duhh, I forgot to add Group By.. Thanks it worked! :)

Comment: Can you explain why you used (*) when Counting?

Comment: @Hashim77  ,  thank for group by ... added .. the count(*) is the aggregatation function for conting row  .. and work based on the group by column you assign ... hope is clear .. otherwise ask  me .. again

Comment: oh so, it counts the fields you select to group by and assigns the count?

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY NAME, ORGANIZATION and count the results using the output of this query. Basically you can include this output in another SELECT statement to get desired result